# Glide with Cronet uses http2 instead of http3 for image download

Tags: android, android-glide, quic, http3, cronet

I want to download images using *HTTP3* and *Glide*.

I [read](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/cronet#features) that I can use *Cronet* to send *HTTP3* requests in android and I can integrate *Glide* and *Cronet* in my app.

According to [this doc](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/int/cronet.html), *Glide* will start using *Cornet* as soon as we add the following gradle dependency -

`implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:cronet-integration:4.14.2"`

Below is my final app level gradle (dependencies only) -

```
// rest of the code

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cronet:18.0.1'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:cronet-integration:4.14.2"
}
```

And my *MainActivity* is -

```
package a.b.glide_cronet;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        Glide.with(this).load("https://<http3 supported server domain>/test/birthday1.gif").into(imageView);

    }
}
```

When I ran my app, it downloaded the image using **HTTP2** (checked from CDN logs) whereas if I open same URL in Chrome browser it uses *HTTP3* (CDN server is configured to serve using *HTTP3*). I couldn't find any example/documentation online to explicitly configure Cronet to use HTTP3 with Glide.

**Question** - How to enable/use *Cronet* with *Glide* so that images can be downloaded using *HTTP3*?

Note - My device's android version is 13.

Thanks